# MSI: How to remove all previous versions?

Tags: windows-installer, removeall

Visual Studio 2010 Setup project.

How I can remove all previous versions before installing the new one in that case:

1. User could install the old version either 'Only for me' or 'For all Users'
2. The new version can be installed too: 'Only for me' or 'For all Users'
   Now it installs in parallel.

I can restrict the new version installation to install ME only or FORALLUSERS.

But I need the new version must remove any installed (ME/FORALLUSERS) before installation.

What need to correct in MSI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Installer can only remove previous versions of the same time.   Per-Machine removes previous Per-Machine and Per-User removes previous Per-User (same user profile).  Mix and match is not possible.

[Major Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369786(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **Note**  If an application is installed in the per-user installation context, any major upgrade to the application must also be performed
>   using the per-user context. If an application is installed in the
>   per-machine installation context, any major upgrade to the application
>   must also be performed using the per-machine context. The Windows
>   Installer will not install major upgrades across installation context.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that all versions of a product installation are identified by an UpgradeCode, as a workaround you can try to create a [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx) which acts like this:

1. get all installed products having your UpgradeCode. You can use the [MsiEnumRelatedProducts function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370103(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. launch an uninstall command line like this:

   msiexec.exe /x *ProductCode*

where the *ProductCode* is the ProductCode returned by the "MsiEnumRelatedProducts" function.

I haven't tested this implementation, but accordingly to Windows Installer docs it should work.

Comment: IIRC, I once read somewhere that you _cannot_ run "msiexec" from within an "msiexec" context/action.